# problems with getting the Element

Tags: javascript

i have a picture the is setting on the event onload :

```
function hideMe() {

        document.getElementById("navy1").style.display = "none";  
    }
```

and i have another function that setting the picture on the screen:

```
    function setUpPicture() {

        subRunnerOBJ = new Object();
        subRunnerOBJ.topPos = 100;
        subRunnerOBJ.leftPos = 0;
        subRunnerOBJ.velX = 400;
        subRunnerOBJ.velY = 0;
        subRunnerOBJ.score = 0;



        snImgObj = document.getElementById("navy1");
```

**//in this point im getting the messge "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'style': object is null or undefined"**

```
        snImgObj.style.left = subRunnerOBJ.leftPos + "px";
        snImgObj.style.top = subRunnerOBJ.topPos + "px";
        snImgObj.style.position = "absolute";
        snImgObj.style.display = "show";

        startMovePicture();
```

any idea why this happan?

```
 //this one will set the the pictue on the right side of the screen
    function setUpPicture() {

        subRunnerOBJ = new Object();
        subRunnerOBJ.topPos = 100;
        subRunnerOBJ.leftPos = 0;
        subRunnerOBJ.velX = 400;
        subRunnerOBJ.velY = 0;
        subRunnerOBJ.score = 0;


        //document.getElementById("navy1").style.display = "show";
        snImgObj = document.getElementById("navy1");
        snImgObj.style.left = subRunnerOBJ.leftPos + "px";
        snImgObj.style.top = subRunnerOBJ.topPos + "px";
        snImgObj.style.position = "absolute";
        snImgObj.style.display = "show";
        //once we place the location of the sub , we will Call to new function that will move it
        startMovePicture();



    }
    function startMovePicture() {

        dt = 50; // in miliseconds
        h = setInterval("moveObj(subRunnerOBJ)", dt);

    }


    function moveObj(someObj) {
        counter = 0;



        while (counter < 3000) {

            subRunnerOBJ.leftPos = subRunnerOBJ.leftPos + subRunnerOBJ.velX * dt / 1000;
            subRunnerOBJ.topPos = subRunnerOBJ.topPos + subRunnerOBJ.velY * dt / 1000;

            snImgObj.style.left = subRunnerOBJ.leftPos + "px";
            snImgObj.style.top = subRunnerOBJ.topPos + "px";

            counter = counter + 50;

            if (counter == 3000) {

                stopRunning()

            }

        }

    }

    function stopRunning() {

        clearInterval(h);
        hideMe();
    }

    //this function will hide the pucture on liad , and once the loop with the Pictue Running will end
    //once loading the page we will not see the Picture 
    function hideMe() {

        document.getElementById("navy1").style.display = "none";  
    }



    }
```

Comment: is this [tag:java] or [tag:javascript]?

Comment: Show us the full code, something here isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

> Unable to get value of the property 'style': object is null or
>   undefined"

This means that you are trying to use a property of an object while that object is actually a `null` or `undefined` value. In your case `snImgObj` is `null`.

This happens because the following code is unable to find an element with id "navy1"

```
snImgObj = document.getElementById("navy1"); // snImgObj is NULL in your case
```

There can be many reasons for this:

1. Your element simply doesn't exist.
2. You have forgotten to set the id or misspelled the id declaration.
3. You create the element *after* trying to get it by id.
4. Your element exists, but has not finished loading yet.
5. ... etc.

**If you intended to create an element by using `getElementById`**, you should use the following approach instead:

```
var element = document.createElement('div'); // creates a dangling DOM node
someOtherElement.appendChild(element); // appends it to another element
```

It seems that older versions of Internet Explorer do not allow to create images in this way, but you can [**read this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/227093/632133) to see how it can be done in cross-browser way.

**Also**

1. The CSS `display` property does not understand "show". You probably want to set it to "block" instead. See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/display) for display property.

   ```
   snImgObj.style.display = "block"; // this is valid
   ```
2. **Always use `var` when declaring variables!** You are polluting the global scope.
3. Don't pass a string to `setInterval`, it [accepts functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval).
4. Use [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) to validate your code. It will tell you where most of your problems are. It's worth it!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `snImgObj` is not getting set to an element in `setUpPicture()`. Double-check your HTML.