# How to create an IMG when I click on a button?

Tags: javascript, html

Now I have this:

```
<script>
 function load() { 
 var el = document.getElementById('load');
 el.innerHTML='<img src=\"load.png\">'; }
</script>
```

And the html:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="javascript:load();"> 
<span id="load"> </span>
```

but that doesn't work, because i may not put `<` and `>` within the `el.innerHTML=''`. Does anyone know an alternative?

TIA

Comment: your script is working for me, at least in chrome, see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bwp8U/)

Comment: please find following code @ http://jsfiddle.net/umUnn/

Comment: Check out `createElement` function of the `document` object; i.e. `document.createElement("img")`. See the OP of this question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226847/what-is-the-best-javascript-code-to-create-an-img-element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226847/what-is-the-best-javascript-code-to-create-an-img-element)

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of `innerHTML` is that you can use `<` and `>` inside it. You have some pointless escaping of quotes, and the cargo-cult `javascript:` [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label), but the script works.

It probably just looks like it is failing because the form submits and the browser leaves the page before the image loads.

Comment: then how should I write it? The escaping was because first, I didn't make a function but just wrote all in the onClick

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery!

```
<button id="button">Click</button>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $("#load").append("<img src='\load.png\'/>");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create the element using `createElement()` method and then append it to your container:

```
var el = document.getElementById('load');
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'test.png';
el.appendChild(img);
alert(el.innerHTML);
```

See this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Bwp8U/2/).

Answer (score -1):

You might try this:

javascript:

```
 function showImage(){
     document.getElementById('load').style.display = 'block';
  }
```

html:

```
 <input type="submit" onclick="showImage();">
 <span id="load" style="display:none;"><img src="load.png"></span>
```

Comment: The HTML is invalid too. You shouldn't escape `"` with `\`.

Comment: seriously, i just copied that line from the given javascript piece of the question. damn

Comment: And while this is a different approach to the problem … you haven't explained what benefits doing it this way have over the version in the question.

Comment: "but that doesn't work" I just wrote something that would work, it's up to other people to say something better if they now it better, like you do..