# html / javascript - <img src=""> loop for add 200+ images at once?

Tags: javascript, html

Hi  I don't know how to loop  the  tag img  using javascript or php or whatever?
I have around 200 images and the name of image is imaged1.jpg , imaged2.jpg, imaged3.jpg,........,imaged200.jpg      something like this....

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
<head>
   <script>
      for(var i=1, i < 200,i++)
      {
         var images = document.getElementbyId("photo");
         //////////////////////////////???
      }
   </script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <div>

     <img id = "photo" src="imaged i.jpg" />

  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/227093/3930193

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best JavaScript code to create an img element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226847/what-is-the-best-javascript-code-to-create-an-img-element)

Comment: Please don't give multiple DOM elements the same `id` attribute. It is not supposed to be used like that. Use the `class` attribute or a `data-*` attribute.

Comment: l'm back. I think It's simple but I forget.  just use php loop                                 for($i = 1; $i <= 200; $i++)
 {
  echo "<img src = 'images/image".$i.".jpg'> <br/>";
 }