# How can i load a picture gotten from an API with Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var loadingImage = image.src(data.points_of_interest[i].main_image);
var bodystuff = document.createElement('img');
bodystuff.innerHTML = loadingImage,
bodystuff.innerHTML = loadingImage,
document.getElementById('outputs').appendChild(bodystuff);
```

That is my Javascript above  and here is my HTML;

```
<section id="outputs">    
</section>
```

The image location from the API response is located here;
`data.points_of_interest[i].main_image`

(do note it is in URL format = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/37/Westminster_Abbey_West_Door.jpg/337px-Westminster_Abbey_West_Door.jpg")

(also it is in a loop hence the use of [i]);

any pointers, please?

My above code only prints out the URL in the console.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best JavaScript code to create an img element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226847/what-is-the-best-javascript-code-to-create-an-img-element)

Comment: a hint could be converting the image first to a base64 string and then use that in an img tag as a source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var src = data.points_of_interest[i].main_image; // URL of the image
var bodystuff = document.createElement('img');
bodystuff.src=src;
document.getElementById('outputs').appendChild(bodystuff);
```

Comment: Worked fine; however I'm now stuck in a situation where I am trying to print out another information e.g data.point_of_interest[i].title, at the same time as printing the image above so that I can style them both; I have tried appending the variable given to the title to the image but nothing works? any pointers? @SandeepNayak