# How do I check if the image size (height and width) is correct from API response in POSTMAN

Tags: javascript, image, postman

I have an API URL like http://example.com/images/crop.png.transform/pictures/image.png which returns only an image. The content type is image/png.

I need to write a postman test to make sure the image height and width are what's required. I tried with the following code but gets the error "There was an error in evaluating the test script:  ReferenceError: document is not defined"

```
pm.environment.get("image")
var url = document.createElement("img");
url.src = pm.environment.get("image");
tests["url width"] = url.width === 640;
tests["url height"] = url.height === 960;
```

Comment: You're adding an image element but based on the code shown you haven't added a source for the img.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226847/what-is-the-best-javascript-code-to-create-an-img-element

Comment: I added the src but still getting the error

Comment: There is no `document` in the Postman environment. See [the documentation](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman-sandbox/)