# How can I create an img element when pressing a button with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

When I click I want an img tag to be generated and with an image I have tried
several ways but it doesn't work.

```js
var oferr=document.getElementsByClassName("a")[0];
var new=document.getElementsByClassName("create")

oferr.addEventListener('click', function () {
    let new_element=document.createElement('img');
    let image=document.createAttribute('src','img/imagen_1');

    new_element.appendChild(imagen); 
    new.appendChild(new_element);
})
```

```html
    <div class="ad">
        <h1>10% discount</h1>
    </div>
    <header>
        <div class="logo">
            <h2 class="name">Environments</h2>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <a href="" class="nav-link">Offers</a>
            <a href="" class="nav-link">Products</a>
            <a href="" class="nav-link">Login</a>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div id="create">

    </div>
    <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is `imagen`? Why are you trying to append a child to an `img` element? They're not containers.

Comment: There's no `class="create"` in the HTML. Did you mean `getElementById("cleate")`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best JavaScript code to create an img element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226847/what-is-the-best-javascript-code-to-create-an-img-element)

Comment: I think you just want `new_element.src = "img/imagen_1"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the image's `.src` property to the source URL.

`create` is an ID, not a class, so use `document.getElementById()`.

The anchors don't have `class="a"`, you should use `document.getElementsByClassName("nav-link")`.

You need to use `Event.preventDefault()` in the event listener to prevent following the links.

You can't use `new` as a variable name because it's a reserved keyword.

```js
var oferr=document.getElementsByClassName("nav-link")[0];
var create=document.getElementById("create")

oferr.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let new_element=document.createElement('img');
    new_element.src = 'img/imagen_1';

    create.appendChild(new_element);
})
```

```html
<div class="ad">
        <h1>10% discount</h1>
    </div>
    <header>
        <div class="logo">
            <h2 class="name">Environments</h2>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <a href="" class="nav-link">Offers</a>
            <a href="" class="nav-link">Products</a>
            <a href="" class="nav-link">Login</a>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div id="create">

    </div>
    <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
```